# Is it possible to associate a POCO entity with a standard entity?

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity, poco

Let's say I have to entities a POCO entity named SalesOrders and a regular entity generated from a SQL database called SalesOrderLines. I would like to create an association from SalesOrders to SalesOrderLines as in the following code but I keep getting the exception below the code. Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
[DataServiceKey("SalesOrderNumber")]
public class SalesOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Association("SalesOrder_SalesOrderLine", "SalesOrderNumber", "SalesOrderNumber")]
    public IQueryable<SalesOrderLine> SalesOrderLines
    {
        get
        {
            SalesOrderLineEntities oSalesOrderLineEntities = new SalesOrderLineEntities();
            var soLines = from line in oSalesOrderLineEntities.SalesOrderLines
                         where line.OrderNumber == SalesOrderNumber.ToString() &&
                            line.StockCode == StockCode
                         select line;
            return soLines;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
}
```

'The property 'SalesOrderLines' on type 'ServiceName.NameSpace.SalesOrder' is not a valid property. Properties whose types are collection of primitives or complex types are not supported.'

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that all I needed to to do was add the [Key] attribute to the generated metadata class.

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(SalesOrderLines.SalesOrderLinesMetadata))]
public partial class SalesOrderLines
{

    internal sealed class SalesOrderLinesMetadata
    {

        private SalesOrderLinesMetadata()
        {
        }

        public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }

        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int SalesOrderLineID { get; set; }

        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        public string StockCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```